# Reading ARGV files one at a time

Tags: perl

I want each (small) file specified with ARGV read in its own array. If I don't test `$ARGV`, `<>` will slurp all files in a single table. Is there a better/shorter/simpler way of doing it?

```
# invocation: ./prog.pl *.txt

@table = ();
$current = "";
while (<>)
{
  if ($ARGV ne $current)
  {
    @ar = ();
    $current = $ARGV;
    if ($current)
    {
      push @table, \@ar;
    }
  }
  push @ar;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of your programs, and declare variables close to their first point of use using `my`.

It is simplest to test end of file on the `ARGV` filehandle to determine when a new file is about to be opened.

This code uses a state variable `$eof` to record whether the previous file has been completely read to avoid unnecessarily adding a new element to the `@table` array when the end of the `@ARGV` list is reached.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @table;
my $eof = 1;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  push @table, [] if $eof;
  push @{$table[-1]}, $_;
  $eof = eof;
}
```

---

[@Alan Haggai Alavi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66353/alan-haggai-alavi) idea of incrementing an index at end of file instead of setting a flag is far better as it avoids the need to explicitly create an empty array at the start of each file.

Here is my take on his solution, but it is completely dependent on Alan's post and he should gete the credit for it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @table;
my $index = 0;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  push @{$table[$index]}, $_;
  $index++ if eof;
}
```

Comment: I always use strict and use warnings... when complexity warrants it :-)

Comment: it happens fairly often that people will present a one-liner that they think shows a bug in perl, when the bug is in their code and would have been revealed by warnings.  you could make an argument that one-liners don't need strict 'vars', but for warnings and the other parts of strict, lack of complexity doesn't mean you should skip them.

Comment: @PhilippeA.: That is a dangerous approach to take. It is just when you think nothing can go wrong that it *does* go wrong because you have become complacent

Comment: That said, I like your solution consisting of a single block and reminding me that $table[-1] can save me a few declarations.

Comment: I have been caught by bugs in  "simple" programs that I felt didn't need strict

Comment: Form is what tilted my vote in your favor. I didn't want to use a separate "continue" block. Also my program has to create an array to start with. This point was not of any importance to me.

Answer (score 7):

The [`eof`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) function can be used to detect the end of each file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @files;
my $file_ctr = 0;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    push @{ $files[$file_ctr] }, $_;
}
continue { $file_ctr++ if eof }
```

Relevant documentation:

> **In a `while (<>)` loop, `eof` or `eof(ARGV)` can be used to detect the
>   end of each file**, whereas `eof()` will detect the end of the very last
>   file only.

Comment: No need to close `ARGV` unless you need a per-file value for `$.`

Answer (score 2):

A hash for array refs of files:

```
my %files;
while (<>) {
  push @{$files{$ARGV}}, $_;
}
```

Comment: Not a bad answer. For my particular problem I needed to load everything in an array. I omitted this detail from my question. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage File::Slurp to avoid opening and closing the files yourself.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Slurp;

my @table = ();

foreach my $arg ( @ARGV ) {
   push @table, read_file( $arg, array_ref => 1 );
}
```